# Nextjs: useEffect only once (if I use Link component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I use `Link` component for open pages without reload:

```
<Link href="/home"><a>Home</a></Link>
<Link href="/page"><a>Page</a></Link>
```

This in my home:

```
const loadedRef = useRef(false)
useEffect(() => {
    if(!loadedRef.current){
        console.log("run")
        loadedRef.current = true;
    }
}, []);
```

This work fine for first load.

If I click on `page` and click on `home`, `useEffect` run again!

I want only and only once load `useEffect` even click another pages and return to home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useRef` creates a value for this specific instance of the home component. If the instance unmounts, then that value goes away. If you want to make a global variable that persists even after the component has unmounted, do something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

// Deliberately making this *outside* the component
let loaded = false;

const Home = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    loaded = true;
  }, []);

  // ...
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

It occurs because the feature "shallow" of next.js
https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing

The official documentation asks to listen to the variable in the query string that receives the request. Generally, this variable is the name of your page like [slug].js. You can inspect the Network tab (F12) to see what is variable used in the query string also.

The below example inspects the slug variable.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

// Current URL is '/'
function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    // in my case the page is [slug].jsx
  }, [router.query.slug])
}

export default Page
```